# How do I "define" two other classes in a class so that I can use their methods

Tags: java, android, initialization

Currently I have already intialized

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

and have no problem using `DatabaseHelper`'s methods in my `Main` class. But now I'm trying to initialize another class

```
expenses = new AddExpenses();
```

and when I try to set the context for that it goes red and when I try to use `AddExpenses` class' method in my `Main` class, my app crashes.

The logcat when the app crashes :-

```
 --------- beginning of crash
10-26 00:44:16.144 4105-4105/project.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: project.myapplication, PID: 4105
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor project.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.getLatestAmount(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at project.myapplication.AddExpenses.recalculateAllSpendings(AddExpenses.java:273)
        at project.myapplication.SpendingTracker$5.onClick(SpendingTracker.java:188)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: What do you mean "use"? Show some code please.

Comment: Have you imported the class "AddExpenses" correctly? It would be helpful, if you show the code of your main class.

Comment: I only imported the class using “Addexpenses expenses;” in the section with all the “import” is and then after the onCreate method for my Main class I defined it as expenses = new AddExpenses();

Comment: I want to use a method called “recalculateExpenses()” from “AddExpenses” class in my Main class but when I try to use it my app crashes, but there are no red highlighted codes preventing me from trying to run the program

Comment: can you show the error when app crashed?

Comment: if you make a constructor for AddExpenses that accept context only then you can pass "this" to AddExpanses when creating its object

Comment: @AsadAli this is what happens when I try to click the button (in my Main class) that calls the "recalculateExpenses()" method from "AddExpenses" class 
 please look at my new edit. 
I tried to pass "this" into expenses = new AddExpenses (this); but error is shown

Comment: post your AddExpenses class